# Error while passing multiple values to single parameter in Mysql

Tags: mysql

`="select * from Table1 where Parameter in " "('" Join(Parameters!Parameter1.Value, "','")   "')"+""` I am geeting  an error in the above query and the error is

> An error has occurred during report processing. Cannot set the command text for data set 'dataset1'. Error during processing of the
>   CommandText expression of dataset 'dataset1'.

I have used this query to pass multiple valuses to single parameter in MySql .In my other report it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some issues in your sql string.  Try this:

```
="select * from Table1 where Parameter in ('" + Join(Parameters!Parameter1.Value, "','") + "')"
```

Should your separator in your Join function come first?  What language are you using?  I'm guessing php?  If so, I think it should read:

```
="select * from Table1 where Parameter in ('" + Join("','", Parameters!Parameter1.Value) + "')"
```

Good luck.